# AngularJS - Way to deal with cache, server validation and updating cache

Tags: angularjs

Im using AngularJS. Due to some resources are heavy to get through the API(from hundreds to around a thousand objects contained in an array) Im caching those in the frontend.

I have a html Table holding this information. Every row displays one of these objects from the cache and provides also selects options to modify certain fields from those objects. When you modify one of these fields, a request is done to the server to inform about changes done to the object.

Of course, there is a need to keep in sync the cache. If I bind the cache data to the table, changes will done to the cache with every action. If the server rejects one of those changes then the cache and server would be unsynched. Without having a copy of the object I would not be able to rollback.

What are best practices to keep in sync?

My solution has been to clone the cache and use this for the table. Changing fields will affect only the copy and a request will be made. Once the server is accepting the request then I updated the cache.

I see this approach prone to mistakes for a future. What I mean with prone to mistakes is basically when cloning the array. This is due to cloning has to be done carefully to really clone things and not get just a shallow copy.

Is there any other way more elegant to work in sync?

I hope I have been able to explain well the issue.

Comment: What are you use for copying objects? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy make deep copy

Comment: What you think about a socket connect http://socket.io/, then you keep some afterSave call the change for the channel and then you update your cache?

Comment: @Scoup we have thought about it in case there we see it´s used in a multiuser environment.

Comment: @Styx Im actually using lodash cloneDeep

Comment: @kitimenpolku I can't see why socket.io can't work in multipleuser environment, if all users are "watching" the same channel everyone will see the trigger with the changes

Comment: @Scoup maybe I express myself wrong. Yes, socket.io would work but my question is more on the pattern design... or ways to face it without introducing a new module/technology.